# Rails time_zone_select to use "official" time zone values

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

My view (haml):

```
= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, nil, {}, class: 'form-control'
```

Renders to:

```
...
<option value="Ljubljana">(GMT+01:00) Ljubljana</option>
<option value="Madrid">(GMT+01:00) Madrid</option>
<option value="Paris">(GMT+01:00) Paris</option>
<option value="Prague">(GMT+01:00) Prague</option>
...
```

When creating a record I want to set the `:time_zone` attribute to the current time zone of the user. There are several ways to do this but after researching I found either the gem `timezone_local` or the JS library `jstz` most common ones.
Either way, all those open source libraries seem to use a different pattern then rails does, e.g the Paris timezone is defined as:

> Europe/Paris

However, the TimeZone object in Rails uses

> Paris

this leads to inconsistencies when I want to create a record with the current time zone of the user as it won't match. I need rails to use the same patterns as `jstz` or vice versa but I don't want to `gsub` strings here or similiar.
What is the best approach here?

Comment: I'm not a Ruby person, but it sounds like you should be specifying `model => TZInfo::Timezone`.

Comment: Hi, I prefer gem timezone you can go with this link https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) to modify `all` and `name` (the list and value methods used by `time_zone_select`):

```ruby
class TimeZoneDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  decorates ActiveSupport::TimeZone
  delegate_all

  def self.all
    TimeZoneDecorator.decorate_collection(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all)
  end

  def self.us_zones
    TimeZoneDecorator.decorate_collection(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones)
  end

  # other custom collection methods

  def name
    tzinfo.name # "Europe/Paris" instead of "Paris"
  end
end
```

And then use the `model` option in your tag:

```haml
= f.time_zone_select :timezone, TimeZoneDecorator.us_zones, {include_blank: "Set from Lat/Lng", model: TimeZoneDecorator}, {class: 'form-control'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.select` instead of `.time_zone_select`:

```
<%= f.select :timezone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.collect {|tz| ["(GMT#{ActiveSupport::TimeZone.seconds_to_utc_offset(tz.utc_offset)}) #{tz.name}", tz.tzinfo.name]}, { include_blank: true } %>
```